# PDF file upload from react-hook-form won't open with SendGrid API

Tags: reactjs, forms, sendgrid, react-hook-form, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a job application form where users upload their resumes, handled by react-hook-form. I can get the resume saved in state just fine, and I can send it as part of a request to the sendgrid API, but the attachment won't open when you receive it via email.

I've been at this for so long, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any advice is much appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
// components/Careers_Application_Form.tsx

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function Careers_Application_Form() {
     const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
     const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('')

     function handleUploadFile(selectedFile) {
          if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
               let fileToLoad = selectedFile[0]
               setFileName(fileToLoad.name)
               let fileReader = new FileReader()
               fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
               let file = fileLoadedEvent.target.result
               setFile(file.toString('base64'))
               }
               fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad)
          }
     }

     const {
          register,
          watch,
          handleSubmit,
          formState: { errors },
     } = useForm({})

     // Handle the submit
     const onSubmit = (data) => {
          handleUploadFile(data.resume)
          SendToSendgrid(data)
          setSubmitted(true)
          console.log(errors)
     }

     // SENDGRID
     async function SendToSendgrid(data) {
          data.file = file
          data.fileName = fileName
          await fetch('/api/sendJobApplication', {
               method: 'POST',
               body: JSON.stringify(data),
          }).then((res) => res.json())
     }

  return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
               type='file'
               onChange={setFile}
               placeholder='Upload Your Resume'
               {...register('resume', {
               required: true,
               validate: {
                    lessThan10MB: (files) => files[0]?.size < 10000000 || 'Max 10MB',
                    acceptedFormats: (files) => files[0].type === 'application/pdf',
               },
               })}
          />
          {errors.resume?.type === 'lessThan10MB' && (
               <p>Error: Must Be Under 10MB</p>
          )}
          {errors.resume?.type === 'acceptedFormats' && (
               <p>Error: Must Be A PDF</p>
          )}
          <input
               type='submit'
               value={'off she goes!'}
          />
     </form>
  )
}
```

Here's the sendgrid API file:

```
// pages/api/sendJobAppication.ts
import mail from "@sendgrid/mail";
mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export default async function sendOnboarding(req, res) {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  await mail.send({
    to: `redacted`,
    from: {
      email: "redacted",
      name: "Pixel Bakery Robot",
    },
    subject: `Job Application: ${body.first_name} ${body.last_name} – ${body.position}`,
    templateId: "redacted",
    dynamicTemplateData: {
     // ...more
    },
    attachments: [
      {
        content: `${body.file}`,
        filename: `${body.fileName}`,
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: "attachment",
      },
    ],
  });
  console.log(res.status(200).json({ status: "Ok" }));
}
```

Here's what happens when I try to open the attachment:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you're mixing synchronous and asynchronous logic. Remove the two `useState()` calls. When you set their values, you won't get the updated values until after the next render. So when `handleUploadFile` returns and you enter `SendToSendgrid` the file and fileName values are probably incorrect. I'd have handleUploadFile just return a tuple of `[file, filename]`. Then on the server-side - you may be passing base64 to SendGrid.  They may be expecting binary...

Check things are multiple points... Some tips that may help you debug:

1. On the server side, ignore the form submission. Read a temporary pdf file, and attache it. Verify you get that working.
2. On the server side, get the form submission, save the PDF file to /tmp. Then open it. Is it correct? Same # of bytes as the original?
3. Dump the data you're sending, and the data you're receiving. Decode it with 3rd party tools. Verify it is what you expect.

EDIT:
It looks like [SendGrid does expect base64](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-email-attachments-with-sendgrid).

You can just use the variable directly without pulling them out of a string template:

```
attachments: [
  {
    content: `${body.file}`,
    filename: `${body.fileName}`,
    type: "application/pdf",
    disposition: "attachment",
  },
],

// change to
attachments: [
  {
    content: body.file,
    filename: body.fileName,
    type: "application/pdf",
    disposition: "attachment",
  },
],
```

Comment: I can get it to send just fine using FS and a specific attachment on the server.

Not sure how to save it to a /.tmp folder. Advice there?

Also the attachments area does need the `${}` around it to work